# converse of left exactness

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

let $i: B'\rightarrow B$ and $p: B\rightarrow B''$ be $R-maps$, where $R$ is a ring. If for every $left\ R-module$ M,

$0\rightarrow Hom_R(B'',M)\rightarrow Hom_R(B,M)\rightarrow Hom_R(B',M)\rightarrow0$

is an exact sequence of abelian groups, induced by $i$,$p$.

show that

$0\rightarrow B'\rightarrow B\rightarrow B''\rightarrow 0$

is a split short exact sequence.

This question come from the Rotman's An introduction to homological algebra.

On his book, this sequnce is exact $B'\rightarrow B\rightarrow B''\rightarrow 0$.

To showing that $i$ is injective. let $f:B'\rightarrow B'/ker i$. How to get that $kerf$ is $0$.

Comment: Try to see what happens if M=B' or M=B''

Comment: I just learned the answer from others. But still thank you.